# MySQL: Data goes blank when try to Update a row

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

So I'm trying to update the Address of a Member in a table. After I click submit on the running page on the browser, the Address value inside the database went blank.

I'm not sure if that means my database didn't receive any data, or it did but the data was considered blank?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    $Username=$_SESSION['Username'];

}
?>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$NewAddress = "";
$AddressErr = "";

$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','testuser','password','Project')
 or die ("Could not Connect! \n");

$sql = "UPDATE Members SET Address ='$NewAddress' WHERE Username = '$Username'; ";

$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die ("Error Querying Database");

 mysqli_close();
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" align="center" style="color:#40ff00">

Address: <input type="text" name="Address" value="<?php echo $NewAddress;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $AddressErr;?></span>
<br/><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should only run the `UPDATE` query when the form has been submitted, not every time the page is loaded. And it needs to be `$NewAddress = $_POST['Address'];`

Comment: You need to move `session_start()` before `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Additionally you are open to SQL injections. Parameterize.

Comment: what's the status of this question? You failed to do anything here regarding comments and answers given.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use 3 variables, first store old data in `$oldaddress` from database and than 
Address:

```
<input type="text" name="Address" value="<?php echo $oldaddress ;?>"/>
```

so it's show the old data to the user when he/she click on edit / update
now `$NewAddress = $_POST['Address'];`
and

```
$sql = "UPDATE Members SET Address ='$NewAddress' WHERE Username = '$Username'; ";
```